# vba listbox to connect with excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error on below line.

```
ListBox1.RowSource = "Tabelle1!A2:C" & loletzte
```

Here is my code:

```
myFileNameDir3 = Sheet3.Range("V10").Value & TextBox116.Text & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Open fileName:=myFileNameDir3, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ListBox5
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "1cm;2cm;2cm"
        .ColumnHeads = True
    ListBox5.RowSource = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'oder:
    'ListBox1.RowSource = "Tabelle1!A2:C" & loletzte
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to describe the RowSource as an address (like `Sheet1!A1:A12`) and not with a Range reference :

```
Dim RowSrcAddress As String
myFileNameDir3 = Sheet3.Range("V10").Value & TextBox116.Text & ".xlsx"

If InStr(1, ws1.Name, " ") Then
    RowSrcAddress = "'" & ws1.Name & "'!" & .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
Else
    RowSrcAddress = ws1.Name & "!" & .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir3, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ListBox5
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "1cm;2cm;2cm"
        .ColumnHeads = True
    ListBox5.RowSource = RowSrcAddress
    'oder:
    'ListBox1.RowSource = "Tabelle1!A2:C" & loletzte
End With
```

Comment: I am getting an error as object variable or with variable not set

Comment: On which line? Because **there is a lot of objects in your initial code that are not set...** so it is most probably `ws1`, `TextBox116`, `...` reference that you are missing or something like that... This code won't work on its own you need to include it into you whole initial code! But see how is constructed and used `RowSrcAddress`.